# Category not displaying in add post, edit post, and categories page.

Tags: database, categories

I have faced one problem after updating WordPress to 3.8.1. When I try to add or edit a post the category list at right side panel is blank, even though I have several categories on the site.

Please see attached screenshot.

[image: Screenshot showing the blank category area of the editor.]

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: This is weird. Can you try to disable all plugins and then enable them one by one and see which/if a plugin causes this?

Comment: Try the code in this answer to your other problem and see if it fixes the problem http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/134977/9884