# No posts found - Custom Post Type show_ui

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I am fairly new to Wordpress (but been on the PHP circuit for a minute) and developing a plugin.  I have created a custom post type with the following:

```
function create_post_type() {
      $result = register_post_type( 'wcdoe_summary',
        array(
          'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Woocommerce Order Summaries'),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Woocommerce Order Summary' )
          ),
          'public'              => true,
          'publicly_queryable'  => false,
          'show_ui'             => true,
          'show_in_menu'        => true,
          'show_in_admin_bar'   => false,
          'capability_type'     => 'post',
          'has_archive'         => true,
          'hierarchical'        => false,
          'menu_position'       => null,
          'exclude_from_search' => true,
          'query_var'           => 'wcdoe_summary'
        )
      );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```

I am able to add posts of this type, but when I go to the Admin page to view the posts, I see "All (48) Mine (19) No posts found".

I have tried this: [Custom Taxonomy with Custom Post Type Finds No Posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136283/custom-taxonomy-with-custom-post-type-finds-no-posts) and saving my permalinks page to no avail.  I do not currently have a taxonomy tied to this post type, but I tried that as well.

Am I misunderstanding what the show_ui setting does? Do I need to set the logic somewhere for the posts to display?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is this hooked to run on the `init` action? everything otherwise looks ok.

Comment: Hi Milo!  Yes it is.  I updated the code above to include the entire function with the add_action call.

Comment: A copy/paste of your code works for me, verify that there isn't something in a plugin or theme altering those queries by disabling plugins and switching to a core-bundled theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just in case anyone else has this issue, my problem was that I was adding a post status of 'published' when I inserted the custom post type, rather than 'publish'.  Hand meet forehead.

Comment: Yeah. It's odd that the status is not in the past tense. If you are using wp_query publish is the default status so you don't have to add it to the area array.

Comment: Saved my life. I made the same mistake.